# multi-user authentication on jupyterhub

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

My JupyterHub deployment uses Okta for user authentication. I have a custom Authenticator which validates the user against Okta, but then returns a specific user `someUser` regardless of the user actually is. This was done to avoid handling system permissions, and to allow easy sharing of notebooks and live kernels across users.

Now I'd like to know who the authenticated user is, for usability matters rather than security ones. I saw on the [docs](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/authenticators.html) that it can be done via `auth_state`. I added some keys to the `auth_state`, similar to what's in the example:

```or-tag-here
class MyAuthenticator(Authenticator):
    @gen.coroutine
    def authenticate(self, handler, data=None):
        username = ...
        return {
            'name': 'someUser',
            'auth_state': {
                'user': username,
            },
        }

    @gen.coroutine
    def pre_spawn_start(self, user, spawner):
        """Pass upstream_token to spawner via environment variable"""
        auth_state = yield user.get_auth_state()
        if not auth_state:
            # auth_state not enabled
            return
        spawner.environment['OKTA_USER'] = auth_state['user']
```

At first this yielded an empty auth_state; I then saw there were some configurations to be applied, so I added `c.Authenticator.enable_auth_state = True` to the JupyterHub config file, and `export JUPYTERHUB_CRYPT_KEY=$(openssl rand -hex 32)` for the JupyterHub process.

However, when I try restarting my JupyterHub service after this, it doesn't load properly. The logs show it keeps trying to do:

`Loading cookie_secret from ....../jupyterhub_cookie_secret`

but there is no proper error message I could find anywhere.

If I comment out the `c.Authenticator.enable_auth_state` configuration, it loads up fine, with this cookie loading line only appearing once in the log.

In the [code](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/master/jupyterhub/auth.py#L50), it's mentioned `cryptography` must be installed, so I made sure it is. I also tried changing the code's default for the `enable_auth_state` parameter rather than doing it via config, but got the same results.

My main question is, what am I doing wrong and how can I get `auth_state` to work as expected?

Alternatively, am I simply going about it all wrong, and should simply stop using `someUser`, and enable easy kernel sharing some other way?